# phonegap android: opening another html file in the phonegap webview

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

i am building a phonegap(v1.3) android(for 3.1 sdk) app. i load the index.html page as in the sample app

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); 
}
```

this works fine. now later on i want to load another  abc.html file in the webview when i call for it from the js through a plugin. **How to achieve a function like this which we can call from a Phonegap plugin.**

```
public void loadUrl(String file){
     super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
     super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/"+file+".html");   
}
```

Or if not this way, **how to load another html in the phonegap webview?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a simple

```
window.location.href = "file.html";
```

was the way. :(

Comment: although you need to use the ChildBrowser and white lists if file.html makes PhoneGap API calls

Comment: no  all js files were re-loaded in file.html, so no need for childbrowser